# Speaker Verification with TRILLsson

Tags: tensorflow, numpy

I am searching for models suitable for Speaker Verification. I stumbled across the TRILLsson models. It seems to be usable for Speaker Verification, but i haven't managed to make it work yet.

I tried to calculate difference between speakers the way it is done in NVIDIA NeMo toolkit's `EncDecSpeakerLabelModel`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
[...]
# m is the loaded TRILLsson model
em1 = m(x)['embedding']
em1=tf.squeeze(em1)
em2 = m(y)['embedding']
em2=tf.squeeze(em2)

X = em1/tf.linalg.norm(em1)
Y = em2/tf.linalg.norm(em2)
X=X.numpy()
Y=Y.numpy()

similarity_score = np.dot(X, Y) / ((np.dot(X, X) * np.dot(Y, Y)) ** 0.5)
similarity_score = (similarity_score + 1) / 2
```

Unfortunately the generated embeddings are quite similar for different speakers. I used samples from Librivox audiobooks for testing.

Is Speaker Verification with TRILLsson even possible?